# Unable to generate assets for build and debug

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

So I'm very new to C#. Just to give some background, I have learned python for about a year, and decided to use the Codecademy C# course just to get used to the syntax and certain differences like overloads (which are awesome btw). Now, I'm switching over to an IDE, and I'm using VSCode. I'm following Brackeys' new tutorial series to get started, and he used the command palette to add something called ".NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug". I click on it the same as he does but I get an error message saying "Could not locate .NET Core project. Assets were not generated." I uninstalled and reinstalled the .NET Core, and even tried repairing it after that but it still isn't working. How do I resolve this? Is this asset necessary?

Comment: Am I the only one who does not know **Brackeys**? Add a link to the webpage/video you are referring too. The command is from the C# extension.

Comment: His videos on YouTube use Xamarin Studio.